# Attempting to move a word to the end of the line with sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, scripting

I'm trying to select all email addresses and move them to the end of the line using sed. I've successfully figured out how to select the email addresses but can do nothing more than append $ to the end - is there a way to combine the & (to paste back in the selected words) and $ (to go to end of line) operators to accomplish what I'm looking to do? Or should I look for a different method?

```
-bash-3.2$ sed "s/[a-z]*@*\.*\.[a-z].[a-z]/& $/" address
Xiao Li, lxiao@unc.edu $, 6705462234, Jackson, NC 764
Elizi Moe, emoe@ncsu.edu $, 5208534566, Tempe, AZ 85282
Ma Ta, mta@yahoo.com $, 4345667345, Austin, TX 91030
Diana Cheng, dcheng@asu.edu $, 5203456789, Matitsi, WY 4587
Jackson Five, jfive@ncsu.edu $, 5206564573, Kyenta, AZ 85483
Adi Srikanth Reddy, sadi1@imap1.asu $.edu, 6578904566, Wyo, WS 67854
Natkin William, wnatkin@imap28.asu $.edu, 8044344528, Richmond, VA 22345
```

*note: these are false names, addresses & phone numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this sed command:

```
sed -r "s/^([^,]+)(,[^,]+)(.*)/\1\3\2/g" address
```

**Explanation**

- `$^([^,]+)` captures everything from start of line upto but not including the first comma (i.e. the first column)  into `\1`
- `(,[^,]+)` captures the first comma and everything upto but not including the second comma into `\2` (i.e. the second column, the email)
- `(.*)` captures the rest into `\3`
- then the columns are swapped using `\1\3\2` backreference to the capture groups marked by the parentheses

Comment: That worked! Would you mind explaining how - or at least explaining the purpose of the \1\3\2?

Comment: Thank you!!! That's a really efficient way of splitting data into columns for manipulation - I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @IAspireToBeGladOS It works as long as there are no commas inside the columns and I dont know how well it will work when some columns are empty. It depends how well the file is formatted.   
Your sed command from the question does not work, because `&` matches only the email column, `& $` append a litteral dollar sign. You dont move the column around.  Therefore you need to match the parts left and right of the email with the capture groups and swap the parts around with the backreferences.

Comment: @LarsFischer Great, great insight about `sed`

Answer (score 0):

Similarly you can do this with perl too..

```
%_Host@User:/home/Gaurava/study/temp> perl -pe 's/^(.+?),(.+?),(.+)$/$1,$3,$2/g' names.txt
Xiao Li, 6705462234, Jackson, NC 764, lxiao@unc.edu $
Elizi Moe, 5208534566, Tempe, AZ 85282, emoe@ncsu.edu $
Ma Ta, 4345667345, Austin, TX 91030, mta@yahoo.com $
Diana Cheng, 5203456789, Matitsi, WY 4587, dcheng@asu.edu $
Jackson Five, 5206564573, Kyenta, AZ 85483, jfive@ncsu.edu $
Adi Srikanth Reddy, 6578904566, Wyo, WS 67854, sadi1@imap1.asu $.edu
Natkin William, 8044344528, Richmond, VA 22345, wnatkin@imap28.asu $.edu
%_Host@User:/home/Gaurava/study/temp>
```